How to get the Delphi TWebBrowser component to scale for monitor DPI?
I built a simple Delphi program to test two solutions provided by Martin Schneider on StackOverflow here:
Enabling TWebBrowser High DPI support
... but when the program is dragged to a monitor scaled to 175%, the page content remains unscaled.
Here's my code for Martin's "Solution 2":
unit Unit1;

interface

  uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes,
  Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, System.IOUtils,
  Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ExtCtrls, ShellAPI, Vcl.ComCtrls, Vcl.ToolWin, System.StrUtils,
  ShlObj, System.UITypes, Vcl.OleCtrls, SHDocVw,
  Winapi.Mshtmhst;

  type
  TDpiAwareWebBrowser = class(TWebBrowser, IDocHostUIHandler)
    strict private
      // IDocHostUIHandler "override"
      function GetHostInfo(var pInfo: TDocHostUIInfo): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
  public
  end;

  var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation
  {$R *.dfm}

  const
  DOCHOSTUIFLAG_DPI_AWARE = $40000000;

function TDpiAwareWebBrowser.GetHostInfo(var pInfo: TDocHostUIInfo): HRESULT;
begin
  // original code from TWebBrowser.GetHostInfo
  pInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(pInfo);
  pInfo.dwFlags := 0;
  pInfo.dwFlags := pInfo.dwFlags or DOCHOSTUIFLAG_NO3DBORDER;
  pInfo.dwFlags := pInfo.dwFlags or DOCHOSTUIFLAG_THEME;
  pInfo.dwFlags := pInfo.dwFlags or DOCHOSTUIFLAG_DPI_AWARE; // NEW added flag
  Result := S_OK;
  //ResizeScrollBars; // will be called by subsequent routines anyway.
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  var wb:= TDpiAwareWebBrowser.Create(Form1);
  TWinControl(wb).Parent:= Form1;
  wb.align:= alClient;
  wb.Navigate('https://google.com');
end;

end.

In this screenshot, you can see the title bar of the test program is properly scaled for a monitor set to 175%, but the TWebBrowser based component isn't:

Here's a screenshot showing the monitor's scaling:

I also implemented Martin's "Solution 1" as shown in this screenshot of the Windows registry:

I'm using Delphi 11:

I'm developing on Windows 10 inside a VMware Workstation 16 Pro virtual machine.
In response to SilverWarior's suggestion, I tried adding browser emulation via the Windows registry FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION key below. Sadly, in no case was the browser content scaled to the monitor's dpi.

Next, I tried browser emulation by Meta Tag. In no case was the browser content properly scaled.

What am I missing?

Based on how Google is shown in your screen shot it seems you don't have Browser emulation set up correctly and thus the web page is shown in IE7 compatibility mode.  As far as I know IE7 did not support DPI scaling.  The second answer to the question you linked provide detailed answer on how to properly setup browser emulation.

Thank you for your suggestion SilverWarior! I tried adding browser emulation, but it didn't help :-( See my test results appended to the original question.

@SilverWarior IE7 had support for HiDPI, but you had to define all sizes in your styles in DPI dependent values. For example you had to use "dp" instead of "px". Web developers failed to switch and browsers started to scale "px".

Switch your TWebBrowser to Edge engine, it has modern support for HiDPI and a lot of other features. Details: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_TEdgeBrowser_Component_and_Changes_to_the_TWebBrowser_Component
Also do not forget to run WebView2 installer during installation of your app. Details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/distribution

Thank you @Torbins, It looks like that's the piece I'm missing. Unfortunately, it appears to be lots of work and will take a few days, but I'll try it.

I thought of a simpler solution, using the TWebBrowser's DOM interface to change page scaling, like this:
procedure Tform.SetScale(const aMonitorDpi: Integer);
begin
  //build css style string for for old IE
  var rStyle:= 'zoom:' + FloatToStr(aMonitorDpi/ 96);

  //set the page's scale
  (MyBrowser.Document as IHTMLDocument2).body.style.setAttribute('cssText', rStyle, 0);
end;

Note that you must wait till the page is done loading before calling this function. I wait 100ms after calling MyBrowser.Navigate().
I also call SetScale(NewDPI); in the AfterMonitorDpiChanged procedure.
